# How to change contents of Word document with Python?

Tags: python, list, ms-word, python-docx

I'm trying to use a word document to change it's contents. When I try the following code, it does not work because `'Document' object is not iterable`.

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document('SomeDocument.docx')
doc_list = list(doc)

some_list = []
for item in doc_list:
    if item == 'something':
        some_list.append(item)

some_list.save('DocumentOutput.docx')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you expect to be able to convert a `Document` to a `list`? I suggest you read the documentation for `Document` to determine what methods it has available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the text in a Word document, you need to use the `text` function from `docx-python`. If you want to manipulate the text of the document you may use a list by storing the text in it, then do what ever you want with it.

```
doc = Document('SomeDocument.docx')

paragraphs = []
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    p = paragraph.text
    paragraphs.append(p)


output = Document()
for item in questions_answers:
    line = test.add_paragraph(item)

output.save('OutputDocument.docx')
```

> ***Please Note:*** This code only copies the **text** of the document without all the **bold**, *italic*, underlined nor colored parts as they are (only their text). Neither will it copy the different fonts, table styles etc.
>   If you do want to copy the styles of each paragraph, please refer to [How do I copy the contents of a word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869423/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-word-document/48925828#48925828)
>   .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the document to a list try using a loop to append all the words in a document to the list 
Remove : `list(doc)` and and change it to `[]`

Then make your for loop and appnd every word

Comment: I've already tried it. It throws the same error: `'Document' object is not iterable`...

Comment: That’s bc your probably still trying to convert it to a list instead of adding it to a list

Comment: No, I opened an empty list and used a for loop to iterate over the items of the document. It doesn't work.