# Python-docx copy header across pages

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have a doc file with a header.
I would like to add more pages to this file and copy and paste the header from the first page into all the new pages.

```
from docx.parts.hdrftr import HeaderPart
document = Document("Template.docx")
document.add_page_break

h = document.sections[0].first_page_header
p = h.part

copyHdr = None
for k in p.package.parts:
  if isinstance(k, HeaderPart):
    copyHdr = copy.deepcopy(k)
    print(k)

newHeader = document.add_heading()
```

I can get the header, but what part or parts I should copy? Where I'll add it?
Thanks

Here is a screenshot showing what I am trying to have.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INgy7.png)

Comment: A header automatically appears on every page until you set a new header (including possibly a blank one). So no need to copy paste.

Comment: Hi @scanny
thanks for the message, I generate a new page but the I don't have a header.
Do you have an example that I can try?

Comment: Check and see whether it is a first-page only header. That one only shows on the first page. There can be up to three headers in each section, default, first-page, and even pages. The default header appears on all pages where it is not overridden. A first-page header appears on the first page only (overriding the default). An even-page header appears on verso pages (left page in book bind, back of page on two-sided print). So if you only have a first-page header and no default header, you'll see the behavior you describe. https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#id1

Comment: yep is a first-page only header, so it is not possible to loop the parts inside the header (image and text) and copy them into a new default header?

Comment: It would be the same approach as when copying a document. There is no direct API support for that, but others have been able to do it, at least partially: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869423/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-word-document

Comment: Yep I saw that example.

So the steps should be: 
getting the Header object by the sections
getting the paragraph, 
accessing the run 
and check for pictures or texts and copy them.

is this correct?

Comment: I think that's the way I would approach it. It depends a little bit on the diversity of the documents your code is going to run on. If you have a pretty good idea what you're going to encounter it's going to be a lot easier to come up with something that works. If it has to work in the absolute general case then that's a much tougher job, which is why it's not in the library yet :)